# Addressing UTCDateTime field in data entity URL for patch method in postman ~ D365FO

Tags: api, postman, odata, dynamics-365-operations, data-entities

Greetings for the day!

I'm trying to update (i.e Patch method) PartyLocationPostalAddressesV2 entity via postman for integration purpose. It has one key which contains three fields in it [PartyNumber, LocationID, ValidFrom]. I need to address the URL.

I'm trying like:

```
D365EnvironmentAddress/.../PartyLocationPostalAddressesV2(dataAreaId='206'PartyNumber='000219507'LocationId='L000007558'ValidFrom='2021-10-20T06:54:04Z')
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
"Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI '">D365EnvironmentAddress/.../PartyLocationPostalAddressesV2(dataAreaId='206'PartyNumber='000219507'LocationId='L000007558'ValidFrom=2021-10-20T06:54:04Z)'. No route data was found for this request."
```

I've tried with filter instead of addressing,

```
D365EnvironmentAddress/.../PartyLocationPostalAddressesV2 PartyNumber eq '000219507' and LocationId eq 'L000007558' and ValidFrom eq 2021-10-20T06:54:04Z
```

and it's working but for updating a field we need to use addressing only as per my knowledge so please help me with it. I know I need to change something around validfrom field. But couldn't find it out. Because while using filter, I got the same error so tried with the single quotes removed for validFrom field it worked. I tried the same for addressing but I'm missing something. Please guide me through it.
Thanks in advance!
I've attached screenshots too.

[This one while using filter query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zIj2l.png)

[This one while using addressing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDJGl.png)

Answer (score 1):

I got this working on my end on a 10.0.20 environment with Contoso demo data.

Here are some of the issues I ran into that I also see in the example request of the question:

- The request in the adressing format includes the `dataAreaId`. This is not needed since the data of the `PartyLocationPostalAddressesV2` entity is not company specific. Including `dataAreaId` with the adressing format leads to the described issue for these entities.
- As in the request with the filter, the value for `ValidFrom` should not be in quotes. This also results in the described issue.

So make sure both of those are fixed before trying again.

For the record, this is GET request that worked for me:

```
{{D365EnvironmentAddress}}/data/PartyLocationPostalAddressesV2(PartyNumber='000000002',LocationId='000000002',ValidFrom=2013-07-02T18:38:16Z)
```

The PATCH request looks the same, I used the following payload to update the street successfully (make sure the payload content type is set to application/json):

```json
{
    "Street": "123 Third Street"
}
```

Note that the PATCH request will return a 204 No Content status code, but the data gets updated.

Finally, here is the JSON data of the record I was working with as returned by the GET request:

```json
{
    "@odata.context": "https://usnconeboxax1aos.cloud.onebox.dynamics.com/data/$metadata#PartyLocationPostalAddressesV2/$entity",
    "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzAsNTYzNzE0NDgyNjszNjMxNDk1NjIsNTYzNzE0NDgyNic=\"",
    "PartyNumber": "000000002",
    "LocationId": "000000002",
    "ValidFrom": "2013-07-02T18:38:16Z",
    "Address": "123 Third Street\nBaldwin City, KS 66006\nUSA",
    "IsPrivate": "No",
    "Description": "Head Office",
    "IsPrimary": "Yes",
    "IsPrivatePostalAddress": "No",
    "IsRoleDelivery": "No",
    "IsPrimaryTaxRegistration": "Yes",
    "CityInKana": "",
    "ZipCode": "66006",
    "IsRoleBusiness": "No",
    "PostBox": "",
    "DunsNumber": "",
    "Apartment_RU": "",
    "DistrictName": "",
    "BuildingCompliment": "",
    "CountryRegionISOCode": "US",
    "StreetInKana": "",
    "CountryRegionId": "USA",
    "IsLocationOwner": "Yes",
    "TimeZone": null,
    "ValidTo": "2154-12-31T23:59:59Z",
    "Longitude": 0,
    "Building_RU": "",
    "County": "",
    "StreetNumber": "",
    "Latitude": 0,
    "IsRoleHome": "No",
    "IsRoleInvoice": "No",
    "City": "Baldwin City",
    "AttentionToAddressLine": "",
    "Roles": "Business",
    "Street": "123 Third Street",
    "State": "KS"
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I tried the way you've mentioned. It's working for get method, and coming to patch it is showing "204 No Content" as you've mentioned but after that while checking by using get method, the value has not changed its holding only the old data.

Comment: I had a similar issue when I tried to update the ```Address``` field directly. Since that information is made up of other fields, it gets only updated when the other fields are updated (e.g. ```Street```). If that doesn't help, please create a new question and post your PATCH query and payload with the expected vs. observed result.

Comment: I couldn't use patch so I used post method in the postman without using either  addressing or filtering. Instead I've sent the values in the body to both modify a value or create a new record. It's working in this way. Thanks for everyone who have spent their valuable time.